# Unity3d NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner in unity and I am having this problem as stated below...

This is loginmenu script which is edited from an asset on unity asset store.

```
//This script controls the UI in the Database Control (Free) demo scene
//It uses database control to login, register and send and recieve data

using UnityEngine;
using System; //allows string.Split to be used with SplitStringOptions.none
using System.Collections;
using DatabaseControl;//This line is always needed for any C# script using the database control requests. See PDF documentation for more information
//use 'import DatabaseControl;' if you are using JS

public class LoginMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
////These variables are set in the Inspector:

//they are enabled and disabled to show and hide the different parts of the UI
public GameObject login_object;
public GameObject register_object;
public GameObject loading_object;

//these are the login input fields:
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField input_login_username;
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField input_login_password;

//these are the register input fields:
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField input_register_username;
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField input_register_password;
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField input_register_confirmPassword;

//red error UI Texts:
public UnityEngine.UI.Text login_error;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text register_error;

////These variables cannot be set in the Inspector:

//the part of UI currently being shown
// 0 = login, 1 = register, 2 = logged in, 3 = loading
int part = 0;
//scene starts showing login

bool isDatabaseSetup = true;

void Start()
{

    //this checks whether the database is setup. It is used to prevent errors for users who try to use the demos
    //without having setup a database.
    //You don't need to use this bool as it will work without it as long as the database has been setup
    TextAsset datafile = Resources.Load("data") as TextAsset;
    string[] splitdatafile = datafile.text.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (splitdatafile[0] == "0")
    {
        isDatabaseSetup = false;
        Debug.Log("These demos will not work out of the box. You need to setup a database first for it to work. Please read the Setup section of the PDF for more information");
    }
    else
    {
        isDatabaseSetup = true;
    }

    //sets error Texts string to blank
    blankErrors();
}

void Update()
{

    if (isDatabaseSetup == true)
    {

        //enables and disables the defferent objects to show correct part
        if (part == 0)
        {
            login_object.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            register_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            loading_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (part == 1)
        {
            login_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            register_object.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            loading_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (part == 2)
        {
            // We are logged in - We have already transitioned to a new scene... Hopefully!
        }
        if (part == 3)
        {
            login_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            register_object.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            loading_object.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

    }

}

void blankErrors()
{
    //blanks all error texts when part is changed e.g. login > Register
    login_error.text = "";
    register_error.text = "";
}

public void login_Register_Button()
{ //called when the 'Register' button on the login part is pressed
    part = 1; //show register UI
    blankErrors();
}

public void register_Back_Button()
{ //called when the 'Back' button on the register part is pressed
    part = 0; //goes back to showing login UI
    blankErrors();
}

public void data_LogOut_Button()
{ //called when the 'Log Out' button on the data part is pressed
    part = 0; //goes back to showing login UI

    UserAccountManager.instance.LogOut();

    blankErrors();
}

public void login_login_Button()
{ //called when the 'Login' button on the login part is pressed

    if (isDatabaseSetup == true)
    {

        //check fields aren't blank
        if ((input_login_username.text != "") && (input_login_password.text != ""))
        {

            //check fields don't contain '-' (if they do, login request will return with error and take longer)
            if ((input_login_username.text.Contains("-")) || (input_login_password.text.Contains("-")))
            {
                //string contains "-" so return error
                login_error.text = "Unsupported Symbol '-'";
                input_login_password.text = ""; //blank password field
            }
            else
            {
                //ready to send request
                StartCoroutine(sendLoginRequest(input_login_username.text, input_login_password.text)); //calls function to send login request
                part = 3; //show 'loading...'
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //one of the fields is blank so return error
            login_error.text = "Field Blank!";
            input_login_password.text = ""; //blank password field
        }

    }

}

IEnumerator sendLoginRequest(string username, string password)
{

    if (isDatabaseSetup == true)
    {

        IEnumerator e =  DCF.Login(username, password);
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return e.Current;
        }
        WWW returned = e.Current as WWW;
        if (returned.text == "Success")
        {
            //Password was correct
            blankErrors();
            part = 2; //show logged in UI

            //blank username field
            input_login_username.text = ""; //password field is blanked at the end of this function, even when error is returned

            UserAccountManager.instance.LogIn(username, password);
        }
        if (returned.text == "incorrectUser")
        {
            //Account with username not found in database
            login_error.text = "Username not found";
            part = 0; //back to login UI
        }
        if (returned.text == "incorrectPass")
        {
            //Account with username found, but password incorrect
            part = 0; //back to login UI
            login_error.text = "Incorrect Password";
        }
        if (returned.text == "ContainsUnsupportedSymbol")
        {
            //One of the parameters contained a - symbol
            part = 0; //back to login UI
            login_error.text = "Unsupported Symbol '-'";
        }
        if (returned.text == "Error")
        {
            //Account Not Created, another error occurred
            part = 0; //back to login UI
            login_error.text = "Database Error. Try again later.";
        }

        //blank password field
        input_login_password.text = "";

    }
}

public void register_register_Button()
{ //called when the 'Register' button on the register part is pressed

    if (isDatabaseSetup == true)
    {

        //check fields aren't blank
        if ((input_register_username.text != "") && (input_register_password.text != "") && (input_register_confirmPassword.text != ""))
        {

            //check username is longer than 4 characters
            if (input_register_username.text.Length > 4)
            {

                //check password is longer than 6 characters
                if (input_register_password.text.Length > 6)
                {

                    //check passwords are the same
                    if (input_register_password.text == input_register_confirmPassword.text)
                    {

                        if ((input_register_username.text.Contains("-")) || (input_register_password.text.Contains("-")) || (input_register_confirmPassword.text.Contains("-")))
                        {

                            //string contains "-" so return error
                            register_error.text = "Unsupported Symbol '-'";
                            input_login_password.text = ""; //blank password field
                            input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            //ready to send request
                            StartCoroutine(sendRegisterRequest(input_register_username.text, input_register_password.text, "[KILLS]0/[DEATHS]0")); //calls function to send register request
                            part = 3; //show 'loading...'
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //return passwords don't match error
                        register_error.text = "Passwords don't match!";
                        input_register_password.text = ""; //blank password fields
                        input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //return password too short error
                    register_error.text = "Password too Short";
                    input_register_password.text = ""; //blank password fields
                    input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //return username too short error
                register_error.text = "Username too Short";
                input_register_password.text = ""; //blank password fields
                input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //one of the fields is blank so return error
            register_error.text = "Field Blank!";
            input_register_password.text = ""; //blank password fields
            input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";
        }

    }

}

IEnumerator sendRegisterRequest(string username, string password, string data)
{

    if (isDatabaseSetup == true)
    {

        IEnumerator ee = DCF.RegisterUser(username, password, data);
        while (ee.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return ee.Current;
        }
        WWW returnedd = ee.Current as WWW;

        if (returnedd.text == "Success")
        {
            //Account created successfully

            blankErrors();
            part = 2; //show logged in UI

            //blank username field
            input_register_username.text = ""; //password field is blanked at the end of this function, even when error is returned

            UserAccountManager.instance.LogIn(username, password);
        }
        if (returnedd.text == "usernameInUse")
        {
            //Account Not Created due to username being used on another Account
            part = 1;
            register_error.text = "Username Unavailable. Try another.";
        }
        if (returnedd.text == "ContainsUnsupportedSymbol")
        {
            //Account Not Created as one of the parameters contained a - symbol
            part = 1;
            register_error.text = "Unsupported Symbol '-'";
        }
        if (returnedd.text == "Error")
        {
            //Account Not Created, another error occurred
            part = 1;
            login_error.text = "Database Error. Try again later.";
        }

        input_register_password.text = "";
        input_register_confirmPassword.text = "";

    }
}

}
```

this is the second script

```
    using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using DatabaseControl;

public class UserAccountManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static UserAccountManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    public static string LoggedIn_Username { get; protected set; }
    private static string LoggedIn_Password;
    public static string LoggedIn_Data { get; protected set; }

    public static bool IsLoggedIn { get; protected set; }


    public void LogOut()
    {
        LoggedIn_Username = "";
        LoggedIn_Password = "";

        IsLoggedIn = false;

        Debug.Log("User Loggeout");
    }

    public void LogIn(string username,string password)
    {
        LoggedIn_Username = username;
        LoggedIn_Password = password;

        IsLoggedIn = true;

        Debug.Log("User Logged in as " + username);
    }

    public void SendData(string data)
    { 
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            StartCoroutine(sendSendDataRequest(LoggedIn_Username, LoggedIn_Password,data));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator sendSendDataRequest(string username, string password, string data)
    {
        IEnumerator eee = DatabaseControl.DCF.SetUserData(username, password, data);
        while (eee.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return eee.Current;
        }

        WWW returneddd = eee.Current as WWW;

        if (returneddd.text == "ContainsUnsupportedSymbol")
        {
            //One of the parameters contained a - symbol
            Debug.Log("Data Upload Error. Could be a server error. To check try again, if problem still occurs, contact us.");
        }

        if (returneddd.text == "Error")
        {
            //Error occurred. For more information of the error, DC.Login could
            //be used with the same username and password
            Debug.Log("Data Upload Error: Contains Unsupported Symbol '-'");
        }

    }

    public void GetData()
    { //called when the 'Get Data' button on the data part is pressed
        if (IsLoggedIn == true)
        {
            //ready to send request
            StartCoroutine(sendGetDataRequest(LoggedIn_Username, LoggedIn_Password)); //calls function to send get data request


        }
    }

    IEnumerator sendGetDataRequest(string username, string password)
    {
        string data = "ERROR";

        IEnumerator eeee = DatabaseControl.DCF.GetUserData(username, password);
        while (eeee.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return eeee.Current;
        }

        WWW returnedddd = eeee.Current as WWW;

        if (returnedddd.text == "Error")
        {
            //Error occurred. For more information of the error, DC.Login could
            //be used with the same username and password

            Debug.Log("Data Upload Error. Could be a server error. To check try again, if problem still occurs, contact us.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (returnedddd.text == "ContainsUnsupportedSymbol")
            {
                //One of the parameters contained a - symbol

                Debug.Log("Get Data Error: Contains Unsupported Symbol '-'");
            }
            else
            {
                //Data received in returned.text variable
                string DataRecieved = returnedddd.text;
                data = DataRecieved;
            }
        }

        LoggedIn_Data = data;

    }
}
```

I am getting error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LoginMenu.Start () (at Assets/Scriptes/LoginMenu.cs:48)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LoginMenu+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scriptes/LoginMenu.cs:173)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: tip. the exception kinda tells you where it failed (hint the class:`LoginMenu.cs` and lines:`48, 173`). I suggest instead of just blindly asking question, try to debug it and find out the problem... go on, don't be shy to use the breakpoints...

Comment: sir I did everything I tried debugged and searched for 3 days

Comment: and well this is my first question on stackoverflow